# Reading and writing of two digit value to file in C

Tags: c, file-io, fopen, countdown, printf

I'm writing a business application in C in which I'm keeping track of a timer by writing the value to a temporary file. The counter starts at 96, and counts backwards all the way to 0. The logic works fine, except when it switches over from 10 to 9, the 9 only overwrites the 1, so instead of 10 -> 9, the value goes 10 -> 90, causing the countdown to start back from this point. Is there a way I can have my application write the value successfully?

I'm using the following two functions to control output to the file"

```
  fprintf(fileFd, "%d" , counter);
  rewind(fileFd);
```

I print the value to my file, then move the access point back to the head of the file for the next entry. Any advice on how this can be done? Thanks, all.

EDIT: Thank you all for the suggestions. I tried the methods suggested below, by calling %02d to write to two place values, and for some reason that completely broke the application. The loops won't happen at all.....then when I recompile, it still won't work until I delete my temp file and create a new one. Now, when writing to the file, it tells me at the bottom (this is a UNIX system) the filename, [Incomplete last line], 1 line 2 characters. Would this make any kind of difference to specifying the number of places to write to?

Comment: if you are implementing a timer, why are you writing to a file?

Comment: You could count from 196 down to 100. That always takes the same number of digits and you just subtract 100 after reading and add 100 before writing.

Comment: For Shamim, this timer is to keep track of server outages over 24 hours from the first time an error is detected, but if the binary gets restarted then the timer starts over at 24 hours again. The value in the file will keep that value alive if the binary goes down. For Lee, I thought about just using a three digit value but it feels sloppy...I was just wondering if there was a better solution out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fprintf(fileFd, "%02d", counter);
```

Comment: Changing my fprintf functions to %02d is causing my application to hang when I recompile and run it....could there be some kind of conflict with writing to the file?

Comment: Shouldn't cause a problem. Is this the line it is hanging on?

Answer (score 0):

Check with:

```
fprintf(fileFd, "%02d" , counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

write to the file taking up certain number of digits, and fill unused digit with 0.

```
fprintf(fileFd, "%07d", counter);
```

The above code will allow time values upto 7 digits.